# Information of ForeignKey and PrimaryKey in postgresql information_schema

Tags: postgresql

What is the best way to see  foreignKey and primaryKey names that are assigned from postgres to columns from its information Schema?

Answer (score 1):

You can see all constraints (including PK and FK) in table [pg_constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html)